# How to change package name already taken in Google Play but not published yet

Tags: google-play, apk, package-name

I have set up a package name like "com.correct.aaa" for my new app in Google Play.
But after I uploaded apk with wrong packege name like "com.wrong.bbb", google play takes my wrong package name, and replace over the old one...

When I re-upload a new apk with correct package name, I got Upload failed "Your APK or Android App Bundle needs to have the package name com.wrong.bbb"

How can I change it back to my original package name???

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new application in the Play Console. It is not possible to change the package name after the first upload.

Answer (score 0):

we can delete the app if it is in draft and create one. but once it is published we cannot delete it.